# Displaying a portion of the link caption in reStructuredText

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am an absolute beginner in reStructuredText and Sphinx for Python documentation. I am giving it a try on one of my existing scripts, an `Emailer` class that handles creating/sending email messages, which uses Python's `email` library. My docstring (in NumPy style, I believe) for one of its methods is as follows:

```
def attach(self, msg: EmailMessage, file: BinaryIO, /, *, filename: Optional[str] = None, **kwargs) -> None:
        """Add an attachment to the :class:`~email.message.EmailMessage` msg using specified params.

        Parameters
        ----------
        msg: :class:`~email.message.EmailMessage`
            The message to add the attachment to.
        file: :class:`~typing.BinaryIO`
            The file-like object of the attachment to be added, opened in binary mode.
        filename: Optional[:class:`str`]
            The name to use for the attachment. Defaults to ``None``, using ``file.name``.
        **kwargs
            Additional kwargs that would be passed to :meth:`~email.message.EmailMessage.add_attachment`.
        """
```

My question is, how do I make it so that the description for `**kwargs` shows up as:

> Additional kwargs that would be passed to [EmailMessage.add_attachment()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.add_attachment)

The `~` operator makes it so that only `add_attachment()` shows up, and if I use `:meth:EmailMessage.add_attachment`, a link fails to generate at all (apparently I need to specify the full origin `email.message.<foo>`?)

As a side, I would appreciate some pointers on syntax/convention. For example, should I remove the type hints in my method signature, considering they are already described in the docstring? Also, how do I exclude certain attributes/methods from showing up in the resulting documentation? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's trying to highlight a row of those`~~~`.  Do you have better results when you escape that char `\~`?

Comment: To link to another project, use intersphinx: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html#module-sphinx.ext.intersphinx

Comment: @mzjn I already have the line `intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3.9', None)}` in my `conf.py`. My question is how do i make it so that EmailMessage.add_attachment() shows up as the caption, without "email.message." preceding it.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 Adding a backslash before the `~` didn't do anything. Neither did putting consecutive tildes like `~~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following markup works:

```
:meth:`EmailMessage.add_attachment() <email.message.EmailMessage.add_attachment>`
```

From https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax:

> You may supply an explicit title and reference target, like in reST direct hyperlinks: 
> `` :role:`title <target>` ``  will refer to *target*, but the link text will be *title*.

"Direct hyperlinks" are described here: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html?highlight=hyperlinks#external-links.

Comment: This works! Small note: I needed to add explicit `()` after the title using this syntax. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Added `()` to answer.